# Renumbering row numbers from mysql question

Tags: php, mysql

How can I either directly in the mysql question or in php get the output to look like this?
Mark that Angelas tips_number 3 is missing in the table and I want to renumbering it to 1-3 in the output. Also only ids with more than one tips_number should have the number after their name.

```
George Danton
Herbert G Wells (1)
Herbert G Wells (2)
Angela (1)
Angela (2)
Angela (3)

+--------+------------------+--------------+
| id     | name             | tips_number  |
+--------+------------------+--------------+
|      1 | Georges Danton   |      1       |
|      2 | Herbert G Wells  |      1       |
|      2 | Herbert G Wells  |      2       |
|      3 | Angela           |      1       |
|      3 | Angela           |      2       |
|      3 | Angela           |      4       |
+--------+------------------+--------------+
```

The closest i get is this

```
foreach($id as $row)
    {
    if($row['tips_number'] > 1){
    $tip_number = $row['tips_number'];
    $name = $row['name']; 
    $result = "{$name} ($tip_number)";
    }
    else $result = $row["name"];       
    echo "$result <br>";
    }
```

Which get the output

```
George Danton
Herbert G Wells 
Herbert G Wells (2)
Angela 
Angela (2)
Angela (4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to know in advance of doing the output that there are more than one entry to ensure they all get the correct display.

This uses `array_count_values()` to count the number of entries each name has. Then it loops over the names - with another loop to output the number of times this name is present.

```
$tips = array_count_values(array_column($id, "name"));
foreach ( $tips as $name => $tipCount )   {
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $tipCount; $i++ )    {
        echo $name;
        if ( $tipCount > 1 )    {
            echo "($i)";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

This will bundle all of the outputs for each person together, so if the elements were spread through the input then you would need a slightly different approach.

Comment: @ Nigel That works really good. I use the output in a pagination (which I should have mentioned first) and when Angela reach a breakpoint after 10 ids her two first outputs which ends a page is Angela (1) and Angela (2) as supposed but the third which starts the next pagination page outputs just Angela. I've also changed the the id column from numbering 1-6 to give each user a id number. It's so it is in the database. Did it wrong in my first post. Sorry for that.

Comment: For paging, you would have to do something like - for the first person do another SELECT to count how many they have altogether, then for the first item on this page you offset it by (number of items in total - number of items on this page).

Comment: Smart and easy solution to fix that issue. Thanks for the help and putting me in the right direction.